# Error: No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly in localhost

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

When i am in my localhost, i got this error.

**No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly**.

Because of this my cron job not working.

How i fix this Issue ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to set cron in your localhost.

1. Step1: Assuming your custom module job schedule time is set
   */5 * * * * (means cron will run job in every
   5 min).
2. Step2: Now run the cron.php (present on root) file continuously on
   browser by pressing F5 button. File path:
   http://localhost/projectname/cron.php
3. Step3: You will see the job has been executed after 5 minutes.

For Second option check this URL  http://www.magentotutorials.in/magentotutorials/magento-cron-run-window-xamp-wamp/

I Hope this will help you.

Comment: Please accept my answer if its helpful to you.